# How to shutdown my windows 10 PC from my raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10, shutdown

How do I shutdown my windows 10 PC from my raspberry pi 3? (I would like to do this wireless if possible)

I have tried:

[Shut Down Your Windows PC Remotely From Linux](https://lifehacker.com/5275652/shut-down-your-windows-pc-remotely-from-linux)

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Couldn't you just have a program running on the computer acting as a server, send some command over the network to the server from the pi, then have the server run `shutdown -s`? You need to narrow this question down, show what you've tried, and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: Any idea how you would do this?

Comment: Which part? Like I said, this is pretty broad. There's multiple parts involved. Have you ever used Sockets?

Comment: no I haven't used sockets and I was wondering how to get the computer to act as a server

Comment: That's a giant question, and the target of many existing tutorials. Google the language you're using and see how to set up a basic server with it. Unless you use a Socket abstraction, you'll need to have a basic understanding of Sockets for the pi and computer to communicate.

Comment: Install an `ssh` server on Windows to make it act more like a proper computer, then `ssh` into it and run `shutdown /s`.